Prometheus default storage retention time
I started Prometheus (v.2.51.2) as a container like appended and expected the flag "storage.tsdb.retention.time to be set to "15d" as default, but it's default is "0s", whicht means endless. What is the reason for that?
docker run -d \
--name=prometheus \
-p 9090:9090 \
-v ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
-v prometheus-data:/prometheus \
prom/prometheus


Where do you get the "Its default is 0s" from?

The default command-line flags after I started the container

This is the default parameters in prom/prometheus, so no idea where you get that from...
sha256:051cb67876a609e838c4be62bf88348ba896b8411d17b3221743a1d31466a114   4 days ago     CMD ["--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml" "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus" "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries" "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"]   0B  (from docker history)
